# ActiveMQ Splitter / aggregator using jms transport

Tags: jboss, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, blueprint-osgi

I have a problem with the **activemq** **aggregator**, would be very thankfull if someone would help me out somehow. Marshaling into a xml.

So i have my route configured like this:

```
<route id="myRoute">
        <from uri="timer:someScheduler?period=5000" />
        <bean ref="someBean" method="someMethod" />
        <marshal>
            <jaxb contextPath="some package" />
        </marshal>
        <split streaming="true">
            <tokenize token="@id" group="1000" />
            <to uri="activemq:topic:some_topic" />
        </split>
        </route>
```

This works and it splits my xml messages composed by 1k rows, tho dunno how to configure the aggregator in order to put together all the messages before proceding with their processing.

This is it(doesn't work):

```
<route id="myRoute">
        <from uri="activemq:topic:some_Topic" />
        <aggregate completionSize="5"> 
            <correlationExpression>
            <constant>true</constant>
            </correlationExpression>
             <to uri="mock:aggregated"/>
        </aggregate>
        <unmarshal>
            <jaxb contextPath="some_package" />
        </unmarshal>
        <bean ref="someBean" method="someMethod" /> 
    </route>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to provide the aggregator with an implementation of an `AggregationStrategy` - this is a class that tells the pattern how to assemble two objects that match the `correllationExpression`. See [Camel Aggregator](https://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) for an example as to how to do this.